# Местность города N

Tags: алгоритм

Наблюдая карту местности города N, программист отметил, что средняя высота любых четырех точек, находящихся в вершинах одного квадрата, равна нулю. Можно ли сказать, что город N идеально плоский?

Comment: Можно

Comment: @AlexzundeR, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Выскажу своё личное мнение, надеясь, что в меня не полетят камни. Конечно, это хорошо устраивать конкурсы на лучший ответ, но ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, пусть вопросы касающиеся чистой математики будут в форуме для математиков, а то мне не, как программисту, хотелось бы читать вопросы, касающиеся моей работы, потому что я (не знаю как остальные), но лично я учусь на некоторых ответах. И несмотря на то, что тэг написан "алгоритм", я так и не смог придумать ответ, где был бы хоть немного имеющий смысл код. Да и остальные ответы не особо то и программируемые. Вопросы, конечно, хорошие... для математиков :)

Comment: go to mathcode, yankee!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что это математическая задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Пусть есть квадрат:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Тогда верно, что:

```
(1)a+c+g+i=0
(2)a+d+b+e=0
(3)b+c+e+f=0
(4)d+e+g+h=0
(5)e+f+h+i=0
```

Посчитаем `(2)-(3)-(4)+(5)`, получим

```
(6) a-c-g+i=0
```

Теперь

```
(1)-(6): a+i=0 => a=-i
(1)+(6): g+c=0 => g=-c
```

То есть противоположные углы в квадрате равны с точностью до знака, а значит `a=-e и e=-i => a=i`.

Получили, что `a=i` и `a=-i => a=i=0`. Аналогично g=c=0

Ч.т.д.

Comment: У вас где-то ошибка. Нельзя придти к такому выводу, т.к. неизвестных больше, чем уравнений. А вы фактически нашли единственное решение. Например (2)-(3)-(4)+(5) не равно (6)

Comment: @FAndES, нет так тоже не получится. В сумме будет присутствовать 2*b.

Comment: А "Аналогично g=-a и c=-i" можете пояснить?

Comment: Блин :( я конечно натупил. теперь всё исправил, опираться будем не на смежные углы а на противоположные. На самом деле разницы особой нет, подход один и тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Не сказано, является ли функция распледеления высот точек над городом непрерывной (всмысле дифференцируемой в каждой точке).
Также, не указана форма города. 
Если считать, что высота города в любой точке может соверщенно не зависит от высот точек в её окрестности, а город не является прямоугольным, то можно привести контрпример:

Треугольный город, все углы треугольника острые. Высота города равна 0 в каждой точке, кроме вершин треугольныка. В каждой из них высота равна 10км над уровнем моря.

Такой город полностью удовлетворяет задаче и не является плоским. Просто для вершин треугольника невозможно построить квадрат, лежащий внутри города.

Answer (score 0):

Можно довольно просто и без уравнений выше, но с долей матана:
Если плоскость непрерывна(в чем я уверен, наверняка), то можно рассмотреть бесконечно малый участок - квадрат, который является плоскостью, и удовлетворяет нашим требованиям.
Как бы он должен принадлежать плоскости OXY просто по той причине, что если он с ней только пересекается, то любой из 4-х квадратов построенных на его вершинах и его центральной точке не удовлетворяет условию. Отсюда можно доказать что любые участки являются принадлежащими OXY.